# Add html header fields to oraclize query

Tags: contract-design, oracles

I want to send an oraclize query as a post function. I use the following syntax:

```
oraclize_query('URL', 'http://...', json_doc).
```

This schema works but without attributes for the html header.  How can I add fields to the header (for example: content-typ, host, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently supported within the Oraclize engine itself, however, it has not been implemented yet within Solidity, and is something we will be adding to our to-do list.

Answer (score 1):

You can add headers with the computation query type. They wrote this library for people to use: https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/blob/master/solidity/computation-datasource/url-requests/urlRequests.sol